# How can I change a file or folder icon using the Terminal

Tags: script, icon, command-line

How can I change or set the icon for a file or folder, in the terminal, do I need to use a scripting language?

Comment: See also http://sveinbjorn.org/osxiconutils

Comment: Note that it does not scale well. Tried to apply icons to lots of directories in one directory — Finder worked very slow.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You'll need the Developer Tools installed, and then the following might work. This takes the graphic in `icon.png` and applies it to `file.ext`.

```
# Take an image and make the image its own icon:
sips -i icon.png

# Extract the icon to its own resource file:
/Developer/Tools/DeRez -only icns icon.png > tmpicns.rsrc

# append this resource to the file you want to icon-ize.
/Developer/Tools/Rez -append tmpicns.rsrc -o file.ext

# Use the resource to set the icon.
/Developer/Tools/SetFile -a C file.ext

# clean up.
rm tmpicns.rsrc
# rm icon.png # probably want to keep this for re-use.
```

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I wanted.

Comment: I'm having trouble with `Rez -append` when working with `.avi` files. `### Rez - Fatal error trying to open the resource file "Video.avi" for writing.`
` any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, it also made the file unable to accept a new icon via the Get Info copy/paste method.

Comment: is there a restriction on the icon size? If I use a large jpg (1024x768) it would be resized to something really small.. Can I somehow retain its original size?

Comment: @nuc OS X supports an icon size maximum of 512x512, so I see no point (well, maybe other than future-proofing perhaps) saving it bigger. And while you're at the command line, you could resize the image's longest length to 512 e.g. with sips: `sips -Z 512 image.png --out smaller-image.png` (though if you'd like to have control over the resampling algorithms, maybe an image processing software is a better idea).

Comment: Note that in recent OSX versions the developer tools are in the `$PATH` (stubs in `/usr/bin` that know where to find the actual tools), and not in `/Developer/Tools` anymore, so you should invoke them just by their filenames; i.e., in the case at hand, as just `Rez` and `DeRez`.

Comment: macOS supports square icon files with resolutions up to 1024x1024

Answer (score 39):

With the benefit of several years of hindsight:

[user588's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6905/28668) and [koiyu's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10020/28668) work well, but they rely on utilities (**`Rez`**, **`DeRez`**, and `SetFile`) that:

- are not installed by default (they come with either Xcode or the developer command-line utilities)
- are now **deprecated** (`Rez` and `DeRez`, because they relate to Carbon)

The **[osxiconutils](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/osxiconutils)** project looks interesting, but **is no longer maintained** and won't compile any longer (as of macOS 10.10.4).

- [velkoon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/272654/velkoon) points out that the linked repo offers downloading **a [ZIP file with (x64) *binaries*](https://sveinbjorn.org/files/software/osxiconutils.zip)** that still work as of macOS 13 (Ventura). You'll have to authorize the binaries for local execution by running the following against the ZIP file before extracting its contents: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine osxiconutils.zip`.
- A notable limitation of the `seticon` utility is that it can only assign `.icns` files, not also other image formats - unlike the `fileicon` utility discussed below.

---

Therefore I've created **CLI [`fileicon`](https://github.com/mklement0/fileicon)**, which **should work on a pristine macOS machine (no prerequisites)**; it is a Bash script based primarily on `xattr`, `xxd` and an embedded Python script that calls Cocoa, courtesy of [this helpful answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161984/28668). [*Update*: Since Python no longer comes with macOS, the Python script has been replaced with an ObjC Bridge AppleScript.]

It allows **setting/removing/extracting custom icons for/from files or folders**, including on APFS volumes on macOS 10.13 (High Sierra). [*Update*: Still works as of macOS 13, Ventura.]

You can install it as follows:

- If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed: `brew install fileicon`
- If you have Node.js installed, [from the npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fileicon), with
  `[sudo] npm install -g fileicon`
- Otherwise:

  - Download [the CLI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/fileicon/stable/bin/fileicon) as `fileicon` (this link will stay current).
  - Make it executable with `chmod +x fileicon`.

    - Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (requires `sudo`).

Here's the usage information; for complete information, refer to the [manual](https://github.com/mklement0/fileicon/blob/master/doc/fileicon.md):

```
$ fileicon -h

Set a custom icon for a file or folder:

    fileicon set      <fileOrFolder> <imageFile>

 Remove a custom icon from a file or folder:

    fileicon rm       <fileOrFolder>

 Get a file or folder's custom icon:

    fileicon get [-f] <fileOrFolder> [<iconOutputFile>]

 Test if a file or folder has a custom icon:

    fileicon test     <fileOrFolder>

 -q ...  silence status output

 Standard options: --help, --man, --version, --home
```

Comment: @Slomojo: [In response to a since-deleted comment] I get that not everybody has or wants to install Node.js, that's why the direct download link is there as well (see the 'Otherwise:` list item in my answer) - it's a self-contained Bash script (the only thing you forgo by installing this way is installation of the man page, but you can get a plain-text rendering of the manual page with `fileicon --man`).

Comment: This is a nice out of the box working solution. +1

Comment: This no longer works in 10.10.  The project has moved to github:  https://github.com/sveinbjornt/osxiconutils if you want to check for an update.

Comment: I realize I'm a few years behind everyone else on this thread, but just wanted to mention that I discovered this today and it's great. Thank you for making it! 

Comment: Works very well

Comment: Still works in macOS 13!

Comment: @mklement0 "and, in fact, was created, because osxiconutils no longer works" I just used the setIcon binary linked on this page successfully today on Ventura 13.0 in 2023? : https://github.com/sveinbjornt/osxiconutils

Comment: Well, thanks so much. I was able to bypass GateKeeper by making your `fileicon` an executable on-the-fly with my AppleScript. Then could set the AppleScript's icon. This is awesome. So now I can distribute the script without any certificates, signatures, app signing, expiration, GateKeeper nonsense, blah blah blah...

Comment: Thanks, @velkoon - I hadn't noticed that _binaries_ are available for download. I've updated the answer accordingly. A notable limitation of `seticon` is that you have to provide actual `.icns` file as input - other image formats are seemingly quietly ignored. Glad to hear the script worked for you. Out of curiosity, how did you turn it into an application with AppleScript, and how does that bypass GateKeeper?

Comment: I didn't explain it well--I didn't do anything impressive. I wanted to distribute an AppleScript to my coworkers. But I wanted it to have a custom icon instead of the incredibly ugly generic `.scpt` icon, so I exported the script as an `.app` and changed the `.icns` file inside. But when you export AppleScripts, you have to apply certificates and all that Apple GateKeeper nonsense or else it won't run (or will run with warnings) when downloaded from the Web. So I instead used `fileicon` within the script itself. https://github.com/wad11656/Outlook-HTML-Signature-Injector-MacOS/releases/tag/1.0

Comment: The key was being able to download `fileicon` as plaintext, then convert `fileicon` to an executable on-the-fly from within the script itself using `chmod`. Otherwise, GateKeeper flags the compiled version of `fileicon` inside the `.zip` if downloaded from the Web. So you giving me the uncompiled version made changing the `.scpt` icon possible, done by running the `.scpt` file itself. aka, Autonomous icon-setting. So now it *looks* like an app when it's still just a `.scpt` file. Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 21):

I *almost* started a bounty on this, because I didn't manage to change the icon of a **folder** using @[mankoff](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/588/mankoff)'s [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-or-setting-a-file-or-folder-icon-programmatically/6905#6905). But I found a solution.

---

To change folder's icon you don't point `Rez -append tmp.rsrc` to the folder but a special `Icon\r` file inside the folder. If you haven't set a custom icon to the folder before, the file probably will not exist, but `Rez` creates it on–the–fly. Deleting the `Icon\r` file will remove the custom icon, so to prevent accidents it is good to be hidden.

These are the modifications to the mankoff's answer:

```
# Append a resource to the folder you want to icon-ize.
Rez -append tmpicns.rsrc -o $'myfolder/Icon\r'

# Use the resource to set the icon.
SetFile -a C myfolder/

# Hide the Icon\r file from Finder.
SetFile -a V $'myfolder/Icon\r'
```

Comment: And for a file? Note my comment re: avi files

Comment: @slomojo sorry, but I can't replicate the error you get—just tested the mankoff's solution with an .avi file. Re-check the file permissions and commands you entered?

Comment: I'll give it another go, perhaps I made a mistake before.

Comment: I am desperately trying to do this for a USB thumb drive. All of the commands "work" in that they don't return errors, but I am still left with a thumb drive with an unchanged icon. Any thoughts and I'd be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Ruby, here's a Python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Cocoa
import sys

Cocoa.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().setIcon_forFile_options_(Cocoa.NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')), sys.argv[2].decode('utf-8'), 0) or sys.exit("Unable to set file icon")
```

`./set-image.py image.png myfile`

Python that pre-installed in Mac OS already has PyObjC so you don't have to install any packages.

Comment: I added decoding of UTF-8 to unicode, otherwise script not worked with non-ASCII filenames. Also added check of return value, failure to set icon will result in return code of 1.

Comment: Is there anyway we can specify the icon not have aspect ratio modified? It works great, but image files get reshaped to a square. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't exactly find the answer, but squaring the images with transparent padding before hand worked just fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179342/imagemagick-extend-canvas-with-transparent-background

Comment: I understand that on macOS Big Sur release, python will be removed.   Would this still work?

Answer (score 7):

Check out [`setfileicon` (source code)](http://maxao.free.fr/telechargements/setfileicon.m), an utility created by Damien Bobillot.

Download the binary here: http://maxao.free.fr/telechargements/setfileicon.gz

After unpacking the file, make it executable:

```
chmod +x setfileicon
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
./setfileicon "my-icon.icns" "my-file-or-directory"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful indeed. BTW, I'm editing out the GUI method, to reduce noise.

Comment: Unfortunately most code is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I have a [github project](http://github.com/RichardBronosky/AppleScript-droplet) where I create AppleScript "droplets" from [shell/bash, python, perl, ruby, etc.] scripts that take file paths as arguments. I wrote this bash function for changing the icon of an folder (because AppleScript bundles are Folders with a .app extension).

```
replace_icon(){
    droplet="$1"
    icon="$2"
    if [[ "$icon" =~ ^https?:// ]]; then
        curl -sLo /tmp/icon "$icon"
        icon=/tmp/icon
    fi
    rm -rf "$droplet"$'/Icon\r'
    sips -i "$icon" >/dev/null
    DeRez -only icns "$icon" > /tmp/icns.rsrc
    Rez -append /tmp/icns.rsrc -o "$droplet"$'/Icon\r'
    SetFile -a C "$droplet"
    SetFile -a V "$droplet"$'/Icon\r'
}
```

Once defined, you call the function with 2 arguments:

```
replace_icon /path/to/AppleScript.app /path/to/icon.png
```

or

```
replace_icon /path/to/AppleScript.app http://i.imgur.com/LmUvWqB.png
```

As you can see the second argument can be an image on your system, or a URL.

**NOTE:** That crazy looking `$'/Icon\r'` thing that I do is because the name of the Icon file ends with a *literal* carriage return `\r`. See for yourself with:

```
find my-applescript.app -maxdepth 1 | less -U
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we have icns-file already. Create temp resource file which points to icns-file:

```
$ echo "read 'icns' (-16455) \"Icon.icns\";" >> Icon.rsrc
```

Append the resource file as value of extended attribute "com.apple.ResourceFork" to a file:

```
$ Rez -a Icon.rsrc -o FileName.ext
```

Show the icon of the file:

```
$ SetFile -a C FileName.ext
```

Append resource file as value of extended attribute "com.apple.ResourceFork" to a magic icon file inside current folder:

```
$ Rez -a Icon.rsrc -o Icon$'\r'
```

Show the icon of current folder:

```
$ SetFile -a C .
```

Hide the magic icon file inside current folder (press ⇧⌘. to show/hide hidden files in Finder):

```
$ SetFile -a V Icon$'\r'
```

### Additional details

Icon data is stored as value of extended attribute "com.apple.ResourceFork" (Terminal command "xattr -p com.apple.ResourceFork FileName.ext" prints the value). For a folder there is magic (which is empty and hidden) file `Icon$'\r'` inside the folder. To extract icon data from extended attribute "com.apple.ResourceFork" into plain text resource file (from which we know correct icns-type identifier "-16455"):

```
$ DeRez -only icns FileWithIcon.ext > Icon.rsrc
$ DeRez -only icns /Folder/With/Icon/Icon$'\r' > Icon.rsrc
```

Under macOS 10.13 High Sierra command `$ sips -i ImageFile.icns/png/jpg` generates error "--addIcon is no longer supported". Switch "-i" means "--addIcon" as extended attribute "com.apple.ResourceFork" onto this file itself using the content of this image file.

Comment: #<stdin>:1: ### /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/Rez - SysError 0 during read.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use MacRuby:

`/usr/local/bin/macruby -e 'framework "Cocoa";NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.setIcon(NSImage.alloc.initWithContentsOfFile("/tmp/a.png"),forFile:"/tmp/file",options:0)'`

You can download an installer for MacRuby from http://macruby.org.

Comment: The link - and MacRuby - are apparently now dead; MacRuby was apparently succeeded by the commercial, subscription-based [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough the best solution seems to be not to use Apple's own tools but the Python code because it has various advantages not being limited by:

- output file resolution
  (it works till 1024x1024)
- input file format
  (tried with ICNS and PNG)
- permissions to install
  (define it as a function)

**Update**

Now (on macOS Sierra) @koiyu’s answer seems to work, so you could use this two-liner to copy the icon from a source folder to your destination folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

DeRez -only icns $1/Icon$'\r' > icon.rsrc; Rez -a icon.rsrc -o $2/Icon$'\r'
SetFile -a C $2; SetFile -a V $2/Icon$'\r'; rm icon.rsrc
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This seems like it would be better as a comment. I know you don't have the points required yet, but I've asked someone who has the power to come take a look. In addition, I've written an Applescript that does all this for you in a neat bundle, see [my answer to a similar question on this SE.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230697/create-icns-ad-hoc/230796#230796)

Comment: Yes, I tried but could not do it. Furthermore I think that the 2nd part of your comment would be better as an answer, not being related to the 1st one.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent macOS version (10.14), `sips -i icon.png` will get a `--addIcon is no longer supported` error.

It also needs Developer Tools installed. This uses the graphic in `Icon.png` and applies it to `file.ext`, just like [user588's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6905/85921):

```bsh
# Covert Icon.png to tmpicons.icns:
sips -s format icns Icon.png --out tmpicns.icns

# Create temporary resource file which points to tmpicons.icns:
echo "read 'icns' (-16455) \"tmpicns.icns\";" >> tmpicns.rsrc

# append this resource to the file you want to icon-ize.
Rez -a tmpicns.rsrc -o file.ext

# Use the resource to set the icon.
SetFile -a C file.ext

# Clean up
rm tmpicons.icns && rm tmpicns.rsrc
```

Comment: I get `Error: Unable to write image to file /Users/uname/tmpicns.icns.4rzX6` on the first command. I even try with `sudo`, not work

Comment: I got the same issue as @leetbacoon . Anyone know why?

Comment: @leetbacoon See https://blog.macsales.com/28492-create-your-own-custom-icons-in-10-7-5-or-later/ for info on how to convert an iconset folder to an icns file. If you need to programmatically create the iconset folder and populate it with png files, use `sips -z x x input.png -o output.png` where x is the height and width of the image, respectively. This will create a copy of input.png with the specified height and width. Then just make sure that the output file is inside the iconset folder.

Answer (score 2):

Much like the Python solution using PyObjC, it turns out it can be done with just AppleScript (which isn't deprecated in 10.15 Catalina, unlike Python and other scripting languages).

I found an example of how to do this on GitHub here:

> [set-finder-icon](https://github.com/pingortle/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/.bin/set-finder-icon)
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env osascript
>
> use framework "AppKit"
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # PROPERTY DECLARATIONS:
> property this : a reference to current application
> property NSWorkspace : a reference to NSWorkspace of this
> property NSImage : a reference to NSImage of this
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # IMPLEMENTATION:
> on run argv
>   set icon to item 1 of argv
>   set target to item 2 of argv
>
>   setIcon to icon for target
> end run
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> # HANDLERS:
> to setIcon to iconPath for filePath
>   set sharedWorkspace to NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()
>   set newImage to NSImage's alloc()
>   set icon to newImage's initWithContentsOfFile:iconPath
>
>   set success to sharedWorkspace's setIcon:icon forFile:filePath options:0
> end setIcon
> ```

AppleScript isn't easy to read, but apparently it's possible to access the Objective-C code to do this through the AppKit framework.

Comment: Thats great. Thank you very much. I was even be able to run this script from Java-Code and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is some kind of a bug (that happen in folders inside de iCloud sync) with the change of icons of "folders" nor files, at last in Catalina: When the Icon change, the UI does not refresh the folder with the new icon when it have an older one. So the second time you set an icon it not refresh all the times. Even if you do it manually with cmd+i and pasting a previously copied image as icon, the iCloud goes crazy with this.

By looking to a workaround, found this little fix (no ideal but works): - this is in JXA Javascript for automation

```js
function makeIcon(theFolder, theFile) {
    var img = $.NSImage.alloc.initByReferencingFile( theFile );
    var updateUUID = newUUID()+".txt";
    terminal("echo -n > "+ sanityzeForBash(theFolder+"/Icon\r") );
    terminal("rm "+ sanityzeForBash(theFolder+"/Icon\r") ); 
    writeTextFile(theFolder+"/"+updateUUID, "_"); 
    $.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.setIconForFileOptions(img, theFolder, 0);
    delay(1);
    terminal("rm "+ sanityzeForBash(theFolder+"/"+updateUUID) );
}

function writeTextFile(fileName, text) {
    var file = app.openForAccess(Path(fileName), { writePermission: true })
    app.setEof(file, { to: 0 });
    app.write( getProperties(text) +"\n\r", { to: file, startingAt: app.getEof(file) })
    app.closeAccess(file)
    return true;
}

function sanityzeForBash(s) {
    return "'"+ s.replace("'","\\'") +"'";
}

function newUUID(){
    return ObjC.unwrap($.NSUUID.UUID.UUIDString);
}

function terminal(c) {
    var app = Application.currentApplication();
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
    return app.doShellScript(c);
}
```

The idea of the "trick" is to create a file inside the folder before to change de icon to force the iCloud to sync, then wait 1s to delete the file.

Comment: You need to `touch` the folder for Finder to re-render.

Comment: I try, but it intermittent change the icon, for the first time it works all times, but not if the folder has an icon ready set. At last this is happen in Catalina.

Comment: I get thinking about you say.... and found the bug, the problem is with folders that are inside the iCloud sync folders that is not happen on other folders that with touch is the only needed.

Comment: Updated code → Found a fast way to update the icon when the folder is inside iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `swift`:

```swift
import Cocoa
let iconSystemFolderPath = "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources"
let iconFilePath = "\(iconSystemFolderPath)/DownloadsFolder.icns"
let iconImage = NSImage(contentsOfFile: iconFilePath)
let folderPath = "/Users/jmurphy/Documents/testfolder"

NSWorkspace.shared.setIcon(iconImage, forFile: folderPath)
```

You can turn it into a one liner:

```bash
swift -e 'import Cocoa; NSWorkspace.shared.setIcon(NSImage(contentsOfFile: "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/DownloadsFolder.icns"), forFile: "/Users/jmurphy/Documents/testfolder")'
```

Tested on macOS 13.5