# Why setting image as its own icon with sips result a blurred icon? Are there any alternatives?

Tags: macos, command-line, script, icon, sips

I've successfully changed icons using the procedure described in an another question: [Changing or setting a file or folder icon programmatically.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6901/1453) Either my `sips` (or Finder) got broken afterwards or I just zoomed in for the first time (it seems the icon is sharp from ≈100x100 downwards), but, anyway, the icon that `sips -i image.png` creates is blurry/pixelated:

[image: blurry icon]

What I did before the blurrification:

```
$ cp FIN-2.png FIN-3.png
$ sips -i FIN-3.png
```

So FIN-2 and FIN-3 are the same. FIN-2 is a 512x512 PNG-file

**Furthermore:** using `sips` breaks *all* further attempts when trying to set a custom icon even with *any GUI method* and with *any file* in *any folder*.

Only cure is to delete `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder/` and restart Finder. Then changing icon via GUI (drag&drop, copy&paste) works normally with any file.

---

Two main questions—and answering to either one probably solves the problem close enough for me:

2. **How can I set an image as an icon programmatically without using `sips -i` (= `sips --addIcon`) in the process?** (again, refer to the [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6901/1453) for more comprehensive info)

   - Shell (bash) or AppleScript is preferred
   - I could convert the PNG to e.g. ICNS if needed.
3. Is `sips` broken? Why/How? Can it be fixed; how? (Or is it the Finder? Or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround!

First off, install [`osxutils` bundle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxutils/) which is a bit dated (2005) but nevertheless it works. (see the [osxutils contents and man pages](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/osxutils_docs))

Prepare the PNG to ICNS<sup>†</sup>—ironically you can use `sips`<sup>‡</sup>. Then use `seticon` from the `osxutils` bundle to change the icon:

```
$ sips -s format icns FIN.png --out FIN.icns
$ seticon -d FIN.icns FIN.png
```

The `seticon` also changes the file's attributes, ie. using `SetFile -a C` isn't necessary.

---

†: Using a PNG as a source file for `seticon` changes the icon to a generic PNG icon, even with `-d` option. Furthermore, using `seticon FIN.icns FIN.png` changes the icon to a generic ICNS icon. (Consult the [seticon's man pages](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/osxutils_man_pages/seticon.1.man.pdf))

‡: NB: the source file *must* be a square and possible side-lengths are: 16, 32, 48, 128, 256 and 512.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough the best solution seems to be not to use Apple's own tools but [the Python code](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161984/50452) because it has 3 advantages not being limited by:

- output file resolution
  (it works till 1024x1024)
- input file format
  (tried with ICNS and PNG)
- permissions to install
  (define it as a function)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I'd recommend taking a look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230697/create-icns-ad-hoc/230796#230796) to a similar question that uses preinstalled utilities but supports features not supported by previous apps. Not sure why it's blurry in this example.

Comment: Maybe I am quite new to _this_ subsite, but not the topic, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31150333/1535581. What are the features you refer to? It's blurry because it uses `sips -i` that seems to be limited at a resolution of 256x256 pixels at the moment.