# Create .icns ad hoc

Tags: ios-appstore, graphics, icon, adobe-photoshop, design

I want to create `.icns` for an app i made, i know how to make icons in png and `.ico` but i don't  know much about it.

Which size should i create my icons before to convert them?
I don't want my icons to look sharpen or blurred.

I tried just converting them but i don't know if it's just a matter of converting png or ico...

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I have used the online tool at [this site](https://iconverticons.com/online/) to create icns files. I am not sure it will help, but I though I would mention the site.

Comment: @DavidAnderson which sizes do you used for the original icon? To not to loose resolution while converting them i mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no point in shoving a low resolution icon into the high resolution icns format. You'll likely need to modify your scaling and make much larger images and then use a tool to assemble the file.

Have a pretty in depth read of the OS X guidelines and the iOS guidelines (which are more complicated, but a shorter read):

- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009882

It's quite a bit of detail on high resolution packing - so you'll likely need a few hours or days depending on how long you've been making resources.

In addition to letting Xcode make your icns resource and the `iconutil` command line tool, look into [tiff2icns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tiff2icns.1.html)

Comment: In addition, I've written an AppleScript to take in an image and turn it into a .icns: I'd be happy to post it if anyone'd like.

Comment: Please do @JMY1000 - edit in or answer here or post a new "jeopardy" question. Ping me and link if it's elsewhere :-)

Comment: @bmike Thank you for the tips, of course, i am not using low resolutions images, i do all by svg so the only important thing for me is to know which sizes i should export the svg to png. Is it `48, 32, 16, 128, 256, 512, and 1024 wide images` ?

Comment: I added a second link for iOS considerations. Apple requirements explanations for naming list these px sizes (duplicates are intentional) 512, 1024, 120, 180, 76, 152, 40, 80, 120, 29, 58, and 87 - see Table 5. Table 6 adds more mandatory and optional sizes for apps provisioned for iOS 6.1 and earlier, @sbaaaang

Comment: @bmike Added :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @bmike 's answer earlier, here's an AppleScript that automates the process of .icns creation.

```
set export_folder to choose folder with prompt "Please select export folder."
set isImage to false
repeat while isImage = false
    set import_image to choose file with prompt "Please select image to covert."
    try
        tell application "Image Events"
            launch
            set test_image to open import_image
            if resolution of test_image = {} or resolution of test_image = {0, 0} then
                error ["Invalid Image"]
            end if
            set isImage to true
        end tell
    on error
        tell application "System Events"
            display dialog "Error: Selected file is invalid" with title "Error" with icon caution
        end tell
    end try
end repeat


try
    tell application "Finder"
        make new folder at export_folder with properties {name:"Icon.iconset"}
    end tell
on error
    tell application "System Events"
        display dialog "Error: Folder \"Icon.iconset\" already exists, will overwrite unless canceled" with title "Error" with icon caution
    end tell
end try

set export_folder_path to POSIX path of export_folder
set import_image_path to POSIX path of import_image
set icon_folder_path to POSIX path of export_folder_path & "/Icon.iconset"

do shell script "sips -z 16 16     " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_16x16.png"
do shell script "sips -z 32 32     " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_16x16@2x.png"
do shell script "sips -z 32 32     " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_32x32.png"
do shell script "sips -z 64 64     " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_32x32@2x.png"
do shell script "sips -z 128 128   " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_128x128.png"
do shell script "sips -z 256 256   " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_128x128@2x.png"
do shell script "sips -z 256 256   " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_256x256.png"
do shell script "sips -z 512 512   " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_256x256@2x.png"
do shell script "sips -z 512 512   " & import_image_path & " --out " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_512x512.png"
do shell script "cp " & import_image_path & " " & icon_folder_path & "/icon_512x512@2x.png"
do shell script "iconutil -c icns " & icon_folder_path & ";"

display notification "ICNS Creator has finished generating an ICNS" with title "ICNS Creator"
```