# Badge count for number of items in a folder on the Dock?

Tags: folders, dock, icon

After clearing hundreds of items out of my Downloads folder, I'm eager not to repeat the process. Anyone know of a plugin/app/hack that will let me badge a folder in the Dock with the current number of items in that folder?

Such a badge would make it very apparent when I need to access/clear stuff out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible, since badges are rendered using code that needs to be included in the app: Finder would need to integrate the code to tell its badge to change.

Consequently, third party apps, in theory, could get the file count of your Downloads folder, and they could code a badge to display it, but they wouldn't be able to access the Finder's dock tile objects: each app can only access their own, and app icons can't only be placed on the area of the dock reserved to folders and document aliases.

I couldn't find any utility that could solve this issue. I'm sorry. It's a great idea though, and I would totally love it if someone proved me wrong and posted an app capable of doing this, for I too have a pretty messy downloads folder.

The only way I found to get easily the item count is the status bar. Perhaps though, you could do a workflow in Automator or Apple Script Editor. I know Automator can make folder actions, which are run every time a file is added to a folder. It would just be a matter of keeping a count, I guess.

[image]

Sources: A bit of research on desktop badges in Apple's [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW4). The examples there all show the desktop tile object needs to be accessed directly within code.

Hope it helps! And good luck.

Answer (score 3):

### [Docktopus](http://startly.com/products/docktopus/1/) will do exactly what you're asking.

From the website:

> Docktopus lets you to place informational badges on your Mac OS X Dock
>   icons (similar to how Apple's Mail displays unread messages). With
>   these badges Docktopus gives you instant access to useful information
>   and powerful commands right from your Dock icons.

[image]

Comment: Ahh that app sure is close. But the badge icon jolts ad stutters around a bit too much for my liking. Thanks for the find though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

Here is a question about setting custom icons for folders: [How can I change a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-or-setting-a-file-or-folder-icon-programmatically)

You'll want to write a program (shell, AppleScript, Automator, whatever) that checks the number of files in the Trash (either continuously, frequently, or whenever something is added), and then adjusts the icon as you desire.