# What are Icon\r files and how do I delete them?

Tags: macos, dropbox, xcode

I notice that within my xcode project I see an Icon\r file.  When I go to the folder where the project is from finder,  I don't see this file.  I believe this is some sort of hidden file that I should not be able to see.  However, xcode sees this file and it's causing some error on my project when I try to archive it.

The following is the error that I got:

```
error: Codesign check fails : /var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
In architecture: armv6
resource added: /private/var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app/www/Icon
resource missing: /private/var/folders/7l/l93zzs6n4h14qb7rmj5r7zn00000gn/T/GtLyx05w1O/Payload/stryker.app/www/Icon
```

Is there a way I can delete this file?  I can't delete it from within xcode.  When I drag and drop it into trash nothing happened and when I right click it, it doesn't give me the option to delete the file.

The project folder is inside my dropbox folder so I think dropbox is the one that put the file there.

Any idea on how I can delete this? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Icon\r` file is used when you're about to change folder's icon: when you change the icon, it is not actually applied to the folder itself but rather to the `Icon\r` file inside the folder in question.

You can remove the file via terminal with `rm $'Icon\r'`

Alternatively, if you want to delete the file through Finder, you must make it visible first; also something you can do via terminal: `SetFile -a v $'Icon\r'`

---

Somewhat related info on how to change file's or folder's icon via Terminal: [**Changing a file or folder icon using the Terminal**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal/)

… And be sure to see [**Icon? file on OS X desktop**](https://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop/298798) on Super User.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.  That allowed me to delete the icon\r and now I can succesfully archive my project!