# how to make a png graphic for an icon into a rsrc file

Tags: folders, icon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal)

ok, my original question was pretty much the same as this one: [Changing a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/changing-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal/10020#10020), but now that I see the commands, my secondary question is with a .png file, (or any other graphic format) how do I change it to a .rsrc file, as required b

Comment: I guess it used tu be done with a program called 'Icns2Rsrc' but the link is expired so can't get that anymore (.icns is in the "any other graphic format" category)

Comment: Isn't this answered by http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6905/9058 already?

Comment: yes, omg, how the heck did I miss that? Anyway, thanks!