# How could I set apple icon image (xxx.icns) to file or folder?

Tags: folders, icon, file

There is already a related question talking about setting a png image to file or foler as icon (
[How can I change a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/how-can-i-change-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal)), but what if my image is an icns?

I know pngs may be extracted from an icns, then follow the solution above. But icns has an advantage that it could fit different sizes. 
So how could I set apple icon image (xxx.icns) to file or folder?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file and click "Get Info" (or press Cmd+I on the file). Drag the desired icon onto the current icon and it will replace the existing one.