# How do i add icon on .sh file using terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, macos

I need to change .sh file icon only for the single file how can i do it with terminal

Comment: It need to be an app not a command line file. SO wrap it in Applescript and alter that icon. Also a shell script wont be in the dock and will open a new Terminal. You might need to be more explicit in what you are trying tu do

Comment: Take a look here, this might be directly relevant to your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/how-can-i-change-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal

Answer (score 3):

Easiest thing to do is is to wrap your script in an app. Platypus (https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) is an easy to use app that can help you do this (and allow you run the script as an app).

Also worth mentioning you may want to look at `iconutil` (`man iconutil`) it will change a folder (normally with the extension of `.iconset`) of png images (icon_16x16.png, icon_16x16@2x.png, icon_32x32.png, icon_32x32@2x.png, icon_128x128.png, icon_128x128@2x.png, icon_256x256.png, icon_256x256@2x.png, icon_512x512.png, icon_512x512@2x.png) into a proper `.icns` bundle.