# AppleScript works in Script Editor, but not in Terminal

Tags: applescript

My **objective** is to create a script that sets my company logo as the icon of a webpage-shortcut-file on user Desktop.

The **background** is IT-management. I want to run a remote script on 100+ Macs to place a branded shortcut to my support portal on everybody's Desktop.

I found a piece of AppleScript that should change the file icon. The problem is that it works fine when I test it in Script Editor, but if I do it in Terminal, it runs, but doesn't complete the task.

Here's the code (h/t [How can I change a file or folder icon using the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/how-can-i-change-a-file-or-folder-icon-using-the-terminal)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript

use framework "AppKit"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROPERTY DECLARATIONS:
property this : a reference to current application
property NSWorkspace : a reference to NSWorkspace of this
property NSImage : a reference to NSImage of this

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IMPLEMENTATION:
on run
    set icon to "Users/myuser/Downloads/supporticon.png"
    set target to "Users/myuser/Desktop/supportpage.webloc"
    
    setIcon to icon for target
end run
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HANDLERS:
to setIcon to iconPath for filePath
    set sharedWorkspace to NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace()
    set newImage to NSImage's alloc()
    set icon to newImage's initWithContentsOfFile:iconPath
    
    set success to sharedWorkspace's setIcon:icon forFile:filePath options:0
end setIcon
```

Running it in Script Editor gives result: *true* (and the icon actually changes).

Running it in Terminal: `My-MBP:~ myuser$ osascript setIcon2.scpt` gives *false* and nothing happens. But I need for it to work in Terminal, because that's how the remote management software runs the script.

As my proficiency level in AppleScript is "monkey pushing buttons", the solution is probably something blindingly obvious. But could anyone help me to figure it out, please?

Comment: Is it really "set icon to "Users/"  why have you left the / off? ir should be "set icon to "/Users/"

Comment: 1. The `#!/usr/bin/env osascript` _shebang_ is nothing more than a comment when the _script_ is saved as a **.scpt** _file_. - 2. If you add `use scripting additions` at the top of the _script_ you can then use e.g. `set icon to POSIX path of (path to downloads folder) & "supporticon.png"` and `set target to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) & "supportpage.webloc"` to avoid hardcoding e.g. `/Users/$USER/..` - 3. In the last few releases of **macOS**, **Terminal** must be given **Full Disk Access** to e.g. **Desktop** and **Downloads** to run `osascript setIcon2.scpt` in this use case.

Comment: BTW That **AppleScript** _script_ was intended to be saved as a plain text _file_ and made executable with `chmod` so as to be run as a stand-a-lone _executable_, hence the presence of the  `#!/usr/bin/env osascript` _shebang_, which I would use `#!/usr/bin/osascript` instead as stand-a-lone _shell script executable_,

Comment: The problem was indeed using "User/..." instead of "/User/..."
Somehow it works fine in Script Editor, but not anywhere else, so thank you!

I also figured out that the remote management software only works if I feed it plaintext AppleScript (not .scpt files) so the comment about .scpt not needing a shebang etc. helped too.

The problem I'm left with is that scripting additions (universal paths) don't seem to work when deploying scripts via the remote management software. Could anyone recommend any other way to avoid hardcoding usernames for 100+ Macs? :S